# Program for a game of checkers segfaulting?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

So I have been working on this project for a while and I finally got it to compile but now it is segfaulting. I have asked my teacher what the problem may be but he cannot figure it out, so I figured you guys could maybe help. My project is to get the program to display a checkerboard and then be able to play checkers on it. The program is seg faulting when I try to display the checkerboard. Here's the relevant code:

Note: Each checker represents a square on the checkerboard-- the value "isOccupied" represents whether the space is occupied by a piece, and "Color" represents whether the color is black or red. The color renders from a separate file I will post. The color can either be BLACK or RED.

this is the output function of the Checker.h file. It's called in the display function of the Checkers class (checkers is the actual game)

```
std::ostream output(std::ostream& otp, int i) const
{
   if (isOccupied) {
      if (i == 1) { 
         otp << B_RED << color << "       @        ";
      }
      else if (i == 0) {
         otp << B_BLACK << color << "       @        ";
      }
   }
   else if (!isOccupied) {
      if (i == 1) { 
         otp << B_RED << "               ";
      }
      else {
         otp << B_BLACK << "                ";
      } 
   } 
}
// THE PROGRAM SEG FAULTS AT THIS LINE, WHICH MAKES ME THINK IT HAS
// TO DO WITH THE DISPLAY FUNCTION
```

display function and the function that sets the board up in the checkers.h file

```
void display_status() const
{
   int i, j;
   for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
         board[i][j].output(cout, ((i+j)%2));
      }
   }
}

void set_board()
{
   checker c = checker();
   int i, j, k;
   for (j = 0;j < 8; j++) { //this block sets up the actual board with no pieces on it
      for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
         string s = c.make_name((i+1), (j+1));
         if ((i+j) % 2 == 0) {
            board[i][j].input(s, B_BLACK, false, false);
         } 
         else {
            board[i][j].input(s, B_RED, false, false);
         }      
      }
   }

   k = 0;
   while (k < 12) { //this block here sets up the black pieces on the board
      for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
         for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            string s = c.make_name((i+1), (j+1));
            if ((i+j)%2 == 0) {
               c.input(s, BLACK, true, false);
               board[i][j] = c;
               k++;
            }
            else {
               c.input(s, B_RED, false, false);
               board[i][j] = c;
            } 
         }
      }
   }

   k = 0;
   int j1; 
   int i1;
   while (k < 12) { //this block fills the red pieces starting with block 64 at the top right corner
      for (j1 = 7; j1 >= 0; j1--) {
         for (i1 = 7; i1 >= 0; i1--) {
            string l = c.make_name((i1+1), (j1+1));
            if ((i1+j1)%2 == 0) {
               c.input(l, B_RED, true, false);
               board[i1][j1] = c;
               k++;
            }
            else {
               c.input(l, B_RED, false, false);
               board[i1][j1] = c;
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And the colors.h file that represents the different colors, in case that helps

```
#ifndef COLORS_H
#define COLORS_H

#include <string>
using namespace std;

const string BLINK     = "\e[5m";          //don't use this your
                   //professor will probibly
                   //beat you to death if
                   //you do feel the need to
                   //use blink!!!
const string BOLD      = "\e[1m";

const string RESET     = "\e[0m";
const string ERROR     = "\e[1;41;37m\a";
const string MENU       = "\e[44;37m";

const string BLACK      = "\e[30m";
const string RED        = "\e[31m";

const string B_BLACK    = "\e[40m";
const string B_RED      = "\e[41m";


#endif //COLORS_H
```

The colors.h is missing a few but I will never use most of the colors so it doesnt matter.

since you guys asked to see the initialization of the board I'm just going to post my main.cc

```
#include "game.h"
#include "checker.h"
#include "colors.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string> 
#include "checkers.h"

using namespace main_savitch_14;

using namespace std; 


int main()
{ 
    string move=""; 
    checkers* c = new checkers; 
    c->restart(); 
    c->display_status(); 
    cout << "where would you like to make your first move? \n";
    cout << "Enter, without spaces, and     which piece you would like ";
    cout << "to move and where(designated by space)\n for example:   A3D4\n" ;

    cin >> move; 
    c->make_move(move); 
    c->display_status(); 

    return 0;
}
```

The board is initialized in `restart()`.

Comment: Use gdb to debug the code. See the stack trace to find out why it segfaults

Comment: @Kieveli: "Writing into the source code"?!?

Comment: Y'know, you wouldn't need those "//1", "//2", "//3" comments to track your opening and closing braces if you just indented them properly.

Comment: @Kieveli: Total hogwash. Your source code doesn't exist in the executable. It may not even exist on the computer on which this program is being run, or on the same continental landmass. You _could_ try to overwrite the process image (which is _not_ source code) but that memory segment is heavily protected by an OS created post-1980, and it's also typically nowhere near either the stack or the free store.

Comment: It seems to me like you have no idea how a C++ compiler operates.

Comment: The compiled executable code might not exist anywhere near the stack in memory. Even if it did, that's a million miles away from the source code. Buffer overflow attacks don't overwrite the original code, they overwrite the return pointer, which is a totally different thing.

Answer (score 2):

Your `output` function promises to return an `std::ostream`, but doesn't have any `return` statement. This results in undefined behaviour and all sorts of nastiness.

Even if it did, streams are non-copyable.

At this point you have two options:

1. **The function should have return type `std::ostream&`, and you should write `return otp;` at the end of it;**
2. **The function should have return type `void`.**

Turn on your compiler warnings: it will tell you about this, and about who knows what other issues.

Comment: this did it, thanks. I cant believe I overlooked something at obvious haha

Comment: I must say, it's somewhat concerning that your teacher "couldn't figure it out"!

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning the `std:: ostream`. 
That can't work!

May I suggest that next time, you compile with `-Wall` or some other alternative flag which will allow you to read `no return value in a function returning non-void`, with a line number, and a whole bunch of other helpful information.

In fact, your code needs to be modified in two ways -- change the return value of the function to `std:: ostream &`, so it is returning a reference instead of a copy, and should have `return otp;` at the end.

Comment: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: Actually, I've taken to using this in my makefiles: `WFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wctor-dtor-privacy -Wdisabled-optimization -Wformat=2 -Winit-self -Wlogical-op -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-include-dirs -pedantic -Wold-style-cast -Woverloaded-virtual -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wstrict-null-sentinel`. Apparently, that's the complete list, for the most warnings. @LightnessRacesinOrbit